# How to fix Jackson rendering multiple namespace prefixes for the same namespace

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, xml-namespaces, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a pojo which I am serializing using com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.

I have a Java class defined with serveral string values.

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(namespace = "http://www.firstnamespace.com", localName = "Student")    
public class Student {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "http://www.firstnamespace.com",localName = "ID")
    public final String id;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "http://www.firstnamespace.com",localName = "Name")
    public final String name;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "http://www.firstnamespace.com",localName = "Address")
    public Address address;
}
```

Address is defined as this and the elements of address are in a different namespace

```
public class Address {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "http://www.secondnamespace.com",localName = "StreetNumber")
    public final String streetNumber;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "http://www.secondnamespace.com",localName = "StreetName")
    public final String steetName;
}
```

When I serialize Student with Jackson, I end up with a bunch of repeated namespaces for the address object.

```
<Student xmlns="http://www.firstnamespace.com">
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <Name>Ken</Name>
    <Address>
        <wstxns1:StreetNumber xmlns:wstnxs1="http://www.secondnamespace.com">Ken</wstxns1:StreetNumber>
        <wstxns2:StreetName xmlns:wstnxs2="http://www.secondnamespace.com">Main Street</wstxns2:StreetName>
    </Address>
```

I am serializing the Student class like this:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
xmlMapper.writeValue(new File("studentTest.xml", student);
File file = new File("studentTest.xml");
```

Is there a way to make a single namespace prefix for a given namespace?

```
<Student xmlns="http://www.firstnamespace.com">
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <Name>Ken</Name>
    <Address>
        <wstxns1:StreetNumber xmlns:wstnxs1="http://www.secondnamespace.com">Ken</wstxns1:StreetNumber>
        <wstxns1:StreetName>Main Street</wstxns1:StreetName>
    </Address>
```

Or define the namespaces at the top?

```
<Student xmlns="http://www.firstnamespace.com" xmlns:wstnxs1="http://www.secondnamespace.com">
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <Name>Ken</Name>
    <Address>
        <wstxns1:StreetNumber>Ken</wstxns1:StreetNumber>
        <wstxns1:StreetName>Main Street</wstxns1:StreetName>
    </Address>
```

I have read that I need to use Woodstox to help with this problem and I have tried the following but I don't see how Woodstox configuration helps fix this. I was able to change the prefix however:

```
XMLInputFactory2  inputFactory2 =  new WstxInputFactory();
XMLOutputFactory2 outputFactory2 = new WstxOutputFactory();

outputFactory2.setProperty(XMLOutputFactory2.P_AUTOMATIC_NS_PREFIX,"foo");
outputFactory2.configureForRobustness();
XmlFactory xmlFactory = new XmlFactory(inputFactory2,outputFactory2);
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(xmlFactory);
```